# use multiple image lightboxes on one page without knowing how much

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a lightbox script which uses a data attribut to know which images are part of a gallery.

To initialize a gallery, I have to do the following:

```
var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox="a"]';
var lightbox = $( selector ).imageLightbox({});
```

If I wan't another gallery on the same page I have to add another:

```
var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox="b"]';
var lightbox = $( selector ).imageLightbox({});
```

I tried to use another selector and the .each function to get it working without writing this 2 code lines for each gallery. But it is not working. The problem is the data attribute groups all images with this attribute to one gallery. If I'm trying it without a, b, c or d - i always get one large gallery and not 3 seperate gallerys.

So, does anybody have a solution how I can use an unknown number of gallerys on one page, without having to define each gallery in Javascript?

I made a JSBIN, so it should be easier to try it out:
http://jsbin.com/goqije/1/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself by doing it this way:

```
$('ul').each( function() {

    var id = $(this).find('a').attr('data-imagelightbox');

    var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox="' + id +'"]';
    var lightbox = $( selector ).imageLightbox({
        quitOnDocClick: false,
        onStart: function() { overlayOn(); closeButtonOn( lightbox ); arrowsOn( lightbox, selector ); },
        onEnd: function() { overlayOff(); closeButtonOff(); arrowsOff(); },
        onLoadStart: function() { },
        onLoadEnd: function() { $( '.imagelightbox-arrow' ).css( 'display', 'block' ); }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Attribute selector](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) maybe?

instead of doing :

```
var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox="b"]';
var lightbox = $( selector ).imageLightbox({});
```

and

```
var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox="b"]';
var lightbox = $( selector ).imageLightbox({});
```

Just do it with a attribute selector :

```
var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox]';
var lightbox = $( selector ).imageLightbox({});
```

Or even better, you can use a naming convention for all the gallery data attributes as follows:

`gallery-1 , galery-2 , gallery-3` and then use a attribute selector as follows:

```
 var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox^="gallery"]';
 var lightbox = $( selector ).imageLightbox({});
```

### Solution two

The above solution seems to have a conflict, here's a slightly different solution that leverages "naming convention" (gallery-1 , gallery-2 ... etc.) and a for loop , see this example here. Notice how I am using a `for loop` to iterate over all the `a` elements and turn their color `red`:

HTML code here:

```
<a href="#"  data-test="test-1">One</a>
<a href="#"  data-test="test-2">Two</a>
<a href="#"  data-test="test-3">Three</a>
```

jQuery code here:

```
$(function () {
        str_elm = $('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < str_elm.length ; i++) {
            data_val = $(str_elm[i]).attr('data-test');
            str_temp = "a[data-test=" + '"'+  data_val  + '"' + "]";
            $(str_temp).css({'color' : 'red'});
        };
    });
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ksn0xtt/)**.

You can change the JS as follows to suit your needs:

```
$(function () {
        str_elm = $('a[data-imagelightbox^="gallery"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < str_elm.length ; i++) {
            data_val = $(str_elm[i]).attr('data-test');
            str_temp = "a[data-test=" + '"'+  data_val  + '"' + "]";
            $(str_temp).imageLightbox({}); // initialization here
        };
    });
```

Comment: Solution one doesn't help, because in this case all gallery's are grouped to one gallery, and I can flip through all images.

Comment: Solution two doesn't work, you can see it here: http://jsbin.com/goqije/5/ I updated the code with your solution.

Comment: @emjay so when you initialize the gallery like this http://jsfiddle.net/e6r8vhx3/ , it works fine ? ..... but as i understand you want to refine your code further , for a scenario in whihc you may have multiple galleries !

Comment: I tried to use your code in my jsfiddle example, but it isn't working. Could you please take a look at my fiddle and make your fixes there? http://jsbin.com/goqije/6/

Comment: change ` str_elm = $('a');` to `str_elm = $('a[data-imagelightbox^="gallery"]');` i am having difficulty running jsbin  , i'am very unfamilier with that tool , also in your html instead of `data-imagelightbox="b"` , `data-imagelightbox="a"` , use `data-imagelightbox="1"` , `data-imagelightbox="2"` , otherwise the for look will have no effect .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78026/discussion-between-emjay-and-alexander-solonik).